# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at StringReader

Tags: java, android, serialization, jackson

Can not deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of `START_OBJECT` token:

```
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3f680180; line: 1, column: 24966] (through reference chain: com.example.warrantycompass.model.AllProductsResponse["result"]->com.example.warrantycompass.model.Categories["Categories"]->java.util.ArrayList[2]->com.example.warrantycompass.model.ProductCategory["subcategories"])
```

Json Response:

[image: Json Response]

`AllProductsResponse`:

[image: AllProductsResponse]

```
package com.example.warrantycompass.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class ProductSubcategory implements Parcelable {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("image")
    private String image;
    @JsonProperty("Products")
    private ArrayList<Object> products;

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    private int _id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(ArrayList<Object> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(image);
        dest.writeSerializable(products);
        dest.writeInt(_id);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ProductSubcategory> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ProductSubcategory>() {
        public ProductSubcategory createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ProductSubcategory(in);
        }

        public ProductSubcategory[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ProductSubcategory[size];
        }
    };

    public ProductSubcategory() {
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public ProductSubcategory(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readInt();
        name = in.readString();
        image = in.readString();
        products = (ArrayList<Object>) in.readSerializable();
        _id = in.readInt();

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to post some code. That error generally happens when you're expecting an ArrayList, but are receiving a single object.

Comment: import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
public class AllProductsResponse {
 @JsonProperty("success") private int success;
 @JsonProperty("msg") private String  message;
@JsonProperty("result") public Categories result; 
  public int getSuccess() {
  return success;
 }
 public void setSuccess(int success) {
  this.success = success;
 }
 public String getMessage() {
  return message;
 }
 public void setMessage(String message) {
  this.message = message;
 }
 public Categories getResults() {
  return result;
 }
 public void setResults(Categories result) {
  this.result = result;
 }
}

Comment: Update your original post, it's unreadable in comments section :)

Comment: These are two class which shows an error in logcat.. Actually i m new to jjackson library.

Comment: Try changing your Categories field to ArrayList<Categories> inside your AllProductsResponse

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7a3dQ.png  getting error in this page

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7a3dQ.png getting error in this page

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly attach the pictures. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!